# How to set the font settings in .pdf, publish via MATLAB and LATEX

Tags: matlab, latex

While trying to publish a .pdf file for .m MATLAB code, equations (written in latex) are not properly rendered in appropriate (smooth) font, instead fonts looks scattered.

I did try to fix the problem by decreasing the font-size of the editor but that didn't work.

For example: the MATLAB code is:

---

%% (a) From above plot there are no signs of convergence of $\rho$

%%

% $x^2+e^{\pi i}$

---

then the .pdf file is not well written, in which equation's fonts are not smooth enough.

thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem, with equation rendering quality being inadequate.

This is my procedure for fixing this in MATLAB R2013b.

1) In the MATLAB command prompt, enter:

```
    edit publish
```

This should pop up the editor for you to edit 'publish.m'. Beware, the file may be read only. Under Linux, I use an external editor as superuser to edit it.

2) Go to line 811. You should see this:

```
    temptext = text('Parent',tempaxes,'Position',[.5 .5], ...
    'HorizontalAlignment','center','FontSize',22, ...
    'Interpreter','latex');
```

Change the value of 'Fontsize' to something larger; I used 30.

3) Go to line 747. You should see this:

```
    swapTexForImg(dom,equationNode,outputDir,fullFilename,equationText,newSize(2),newSize(1))
```

Change that to

```
    swapTexForImg(dom,equationNode,outputDir,fullFilename,equationText,newSize(2)/scale,newSize(1)/scale)
```

where *scale* is the scale factor of your liking. Might have to play with it a bit until you get it right; I used 2.

4) Save the file. Also keep a backup of the original.

5) In the MATLAB command prompt, enter:

```
rehash toolboxcache
```

followed by:

```
clear functions
```

6) Run publish again.

This should do the job for the PDF. I haven't tried it for HTML, but it should also work. In case of HTMl, don't forget to delete the images created previously.

Comment: Great job ! it worked, I just tested. 
Just a small edit for MATLABR2013a users that line numbers that you defined above are: 780 and 717 respectively. Font size of 70 and scale of 2 worked for me.

Comment: Comment taken from a NAA of mmarshal *This doesn't work in MATLAB 2015a. Changes to 'publish.m' are disregarded even after rehash toolboxcache and clear functions*

Comment: For MATLAB 2015b, I needed to modify `swapTexForImg(...newSize(2)/scale,newSize(1)/scale)` to be `swapTexForImg(..., round(newSize(2)/scale),round(newSize(1)/scale))`. Also, you will need to remove (i.e., backup to another directory) `publish.p` (you can find this file with the Matlab command `which publish`)

Comment: In MATLAB 2015b, you also need to edit a second call to `swapTexForImg` which checks for the cached images. The function call should be modified in exactly the same manner.

Comment: Newer versions of MATLAB seem to use a `pcode`'d version of the `publish.m` file. So you need to also run the following after you have saved your edits to `publish.m` (taken from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/213344-how-to-get-matlab-to-reload-its-cached-internal-m-files)): `pcode publish.m`