# Matlab table font size

Tags: matlab, formatting

I've written a matlab file that outputs a table of values.  The code itself works exactly as I want it to, but when I publish to pdf, the table format lays the values of the last column on top of first column.  I'd like to make the font size smaller so that my table can look nice.  I found some related ideas on this, but couldn't implement them correctly.  How do I shrink the font size?  Here is my matlab code:

```
format shorte

f = @(x) exp(x);
R1 = @(h) (f(h)-f(0))/h;
R2 = @(h) (1/h)*((-3/2)*f(0)+2*f(h)-(1/2)*f(2*h));
E1 = @(h) abs(R1(h)-1);
E2 = @(h) abs(R2(h)-1);

h = zeros(16,1);
for i=1:16
    h(i)= 10^(-i);
end

fA = zeros(16,1);
for i=1:16
    fA(i)=f(h(i));
end

r1 = zeros(16,1);
for i=1:16
    r1(i)=R1(h(i));
end

r2 = zeros(16,1);
for i=1:16
    r2(i)=R2(h(i));
end

e1 = zeros(16,1);
for i=1:16
    e1(i)=E1(h(i));
end

e2 = zeros(16,1);
for i=1:16
    e2(i)=E2(h(i));
end

T = table(h, r1, e1, r2, e2);
T
```

Comment: The answer probably lies in how you're publishing to PDF. What approach are you using for this?

Comment: To publish to pdf I go to the publish tab, click the arrow under the publish button on the right, click edit publishing options, click html in the top right cell, and select pdf from the options.  Then I publish.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948601/how-to-set-the-font-settings-in-pdf-publish-via-matlab-and-latex